# R Studio : loop on data frame

Tags: r, database, loops

I'm using R Studio to treat data and I have a huge file on excel to treat. So to make it simple, I have 3 columns : Subject, Date+hour, Measure. I had no difficulties to insert the data frame in R and associate the right class to each column.

For each subject, we measure a variable during 5 or 6 mins. But we see this 5-6 mins with a date and an hour : for example
[Tab1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P5dkP.png)

(It is a machine that is taking the measurement, that's why you got it like this).
So what I want to do is create a new column "Time" in which I will put the time of record for EACH subject. So it means that overtime we change the subject, we have a new time 0 at which we start the record (I hope it's clear). 
So with this example, my data is named Essai :
[Tab2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xeq02.png)

So I guess I have to do a double loop with for.

First, I create the vector in which I will put the time values :

```
    Time<-c()
    Time<-as.numeric(as.vector(Time))
```

- First question : Should I create a vector with the same number of rows than in my data frame ?

Then, I'm trying to test a first loop (because I have no idea how to create the big one) for the first subject :

```
    for (i in 1:length(Subject)) {
       while (Essai$Subject[i]=="1") {
       Time<-append(Essai$Time, Essai$Date[i]-Essai$Date[1])
       }
    }
    Essai<-cbind(Essai, Time)
```

This doesn't work. I only see "1" in each row of Time...

I was wondering if it was a class problem. Because for the date, I put :

```
 Essai$Date<-as.POSIXlt(Essai$Date, format = "%Y/%m/%d/%H:%M:%S")
```

And when I ask :

```
 Essai$Date[3]-Essai$Date[1]
```

I got : 2 sec.
So that's not the problem... I guess I don't know how to write a loop very well with data frame.
If someone could help me, I will be super grateful !

Thanks
Thiphaine

Comment: can you post some sample data. So it is more easy to understand your question.

Comment: Can you also perhaps give an example of how you would like the output, because I don't fully understand what you want... And perhaps give an example of your data, so we can work with it (so no images).

Comment: about the output, I would like a new column called "Time" in which I will have the time of record for each subject. I'm gonna try to put an example of my data, I'm just not sure about how to do it

Comment: Okay, I tried to put the data on the post! Hope it's okay like this